# Why is my tableview only showing dates in ascending order and not the rest of my data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I've made an RSS feed app that collects the feed items from multiple websites and posts them on a UITableView, I've tried order the results by date ascending and at the moment the only thing being ordered is the data and the rest of my data such as 'name' and 'description' and being muddled around into random orders and not aligning with the date.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                    sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pubDate"
                                    ascending:YES];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *date = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
NSDate *finalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"displayDate = %@", finalDate);



NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedEventArray = [feeds
                             sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];




cell.customName.text = [[sortedEventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"author"];


cell.customDescription.text = [[sortedEventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];

cell.customDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", finalDate];

(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {


    item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    author   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    description    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    pubDate    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];



}

}

(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"author"]) {
    [author appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"])
{
    [link appendString:string];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"])
{
    [description appendString:string];
}
else if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
{
    [pubDate appendString:string];
}



}

(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

     [self.tableView reloadData];

}

(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    link = [NSMutableString stringWithString:
    [link stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    pubDate = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[pubDate stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];


    [item setObject:author forKey:@"author"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
    [item setObject:pubDate forKey:@"pubDate"];


    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting should not be done at all cellForRowAtIndexPath.  That method is called repeatedly as the table scrolls. Instead, insert the xml items into a correctly sorted position as they are completed.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    // your existing code
    NSComparator comparator = ^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
        return [a[@"pubDate"] compare:b[@"pubDate"]];
    };
    NSUinteger index = [feeds indexOfObject:item
                              inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [feeds count])
                                    options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                            usingComparator:comparator];

    [feeds insertObject:[item copy] atIndex:index];
}
```

Don't do any sorting or manipulation of `feeds` in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Just get the item....

```
NSDictionary *myModel = feeds[indexPath.row];
// and use it
cell.customName.text = myModel[@"author"];
```

Much less code, and much less computation where it counts.

**EDIT**

Your date interpretation code is great, but it's misplaced.  By doing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: it gets done, then thrown out, then redone, and so on.  Also, it gets done too late to be useful in the sort, where we need it.

Instead, get an `NSDate` built during the parse, and keep it.  It's needed for the sort, and for any other date computation you might do elsewhere in the app.

```
// first, abstract your (perfectly good) date parse to it's own function
- (NSDate *)dateFromXml:(NSString *)dateString {

    // with static declaration, we'll create the date formatter only once
    // better than creating a formatter for every date we parse
    static NSDateFormatter *df;
    if (!df) {
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    }
    return [df dateFromString: dateString];
}
```

Now, let's add our NSDate representation to the parsed xml.  From now on, pubDate is just for display, we'll add another key called pubDateObj to do any date computation with, like sorting:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    // your existing code
    // now add the new pubDateObj to the parse
    item[@"pubDateObj"] = [self dateFromXml:item[@"pubDate"]];

    // the sort code I suggest above, except:    
    NSComparator comparator = ^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
        return [a[@"pubDateObj"] compare:b[@"pubDateObj"]];
    };
    // and so on as before
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes - lots of bumps smoothed out pretty well :-)

Comment: Runs a lot smoother but for some reason the data is still in a scrambled order and not ascending from the date. Any ideas?

Comment: How about, after the insert, NSLog(@"%@", feeds);  see if it's sorted how you expect.  If it is, then there's a mistake in how you're accessing it in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Yeah I figured out it's sorting them by day, and in random days as well. Starts with Friday then to monday then to saturday etc... Strange. Thanks for the help so far, but could this be to do with the format of the date? I've NSLogged the feed and it's producing the same sorting as the TableView.

Comment: Oh. That's lexical order. It means that pubDate isn't an NSDate. It must be a string starting with the day. Please paste a pubDate e.g. here. We'll get it sorted.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSString *date = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
    NSDate *finalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];

    cell.customDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", finalDate];


The date Format on the RSS Feed is as follows,

<pubDate>Sun, 04 May 2014 02:51:45 +0100</pubDate>

Comment: Great I think it's nearly there, just having a little issue on what to put on the cell to display the date on customDate label, I've tried declaring it as an NSDate and putting cell.customDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pubDateObj]; but it's returning NULL, sorry I know this is probably simple. Thanks Again.

and cell.customDate.text = [cellItem objectForKey:@"pubDateObj"];
is giving me an error "-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac88020"

Comment: Right - that's why we keep the original pubDate.  Its already a string.  So you use the pubDateObj for computation and pubDate for display in the UI.  (if you want another string format like "5/4/14", then add another key like pubDateShortString or whatever, and format it during the xml parse.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `date` variable from the unsorted `feeds` array, but take other data from the sorted `sortedEventArray` array.

```
NSString *date = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
NSDate *finalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

Then later after building the sorted array:

```
cell.customName.text = [[sortedEventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"author"];
cell.customDescription.text = [[sortedEventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];

cell.customDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", finalDate];
```

You should move the two lines where you set the finalDate after building the sorted array like so:

```
NSArray *sortedEventArray = [feeds
                         sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
// Put the two lines here and access the sorted array:
NSString *date = [[sortedEventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
NSDate *finalDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

EDIT:

You probably should fetch the array element once and then use it as needed:

```
NSDictionary *cellItem = [sortedEventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.customName.text = [cellItem objectForKey: @"author"];
cell.customDescription.text = [cellItem objectForKey: @"description"];
// and so on...
```

Comment: I would advise against sorting (and resorting) the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I agree, that sorting should be moved out of that function... It should be done as soon as the sorting problem is solved - on the other hand, things may well become easier with the major bumps smoothed out...